# Зависимости расширений PHP

Tags: php, extension

В моем `PHP` проекте есть несколько расширений, таких как `PhpThread`, `PhpRedis`. При публикации проекта мне надо как-то указать что проект зависим от этих расширений для интерпретатора.

Естественно в `composer.json` мне эти зависимости не указать, как будет правильно указать что интерпретатор зависим от этих расширений?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Достаточно указать имя расширения с префиксом `ext-`:

```
{
  "require": {
    "ext-phpredis": "*"
  }
}
```

Имена расширений [с точки зрения Composer](https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/0f373e3249b0d9523c94766d69d47676f190fdb4/src/Composer/Repository/PlatformRepository.php#L109) можно посмотреть так:

```
<?php
var_dump(get_loaded_extensions());
```

Answer (score 0):

Куда писать не знаю, но знаю, что если строго зависим, то стоит делать проверку на наличие этого расширения `extension_loaded()`, и не важно описали вы это где-то или нет, в случае отсутствия выдавать ошибки, так все делают :)

Comment: Да как бы, у меня устанавливаются такие расширения которые при не верном запуске соответственно и отсутствии будут выкидывать исключения, которые я успешно ловлю. Это проверка не то чтобы отвечает на мой вопрос. :)